# Thelia: How can I query Categories by URL?

Tags: symfony

Thelia newbie here. I am simply trying to query a Category by its (English) URL. I can get a `RewritingUrlQuery` to find the correct `rewriting_url` row, but I can't figure out how to incorporate this into a `CategoryQuery`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public function showAction($slug) {
  $urlFilter = RewritingUrlQuery::create()
    ->filterByUrl($slug);

  $category = CategoryQuery::create()
    ->filterBy('url', $urlFilter)
    ->findOne();
```

Not surprisingly, this fails with the error message "Unknown column url in model Thelia\Model\Category". I'm wondering if there's a `CategoryQuery` method I should be using other than `filterBy`, or a slightly different approach to querying categories? I can't imagine Thelia/Symfony doesn't provide a way to do something this simple...

Comment: Can you add more detail? Does category has a slug field? what is thelia? What is an url filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple, as I suspected! :)

I simply had to get the `viewId` (the ID of the category represented at the URL) from the returned `RewritingUrl` object, and then use that ID in a `CategoryQuery`:

```
$urlFilter = RewritingUrlQuery::create()
  ->filterByView('category')
  ->filterByUrl($slug)
  ->findOne();

$category = CategoryQuery::create()
  ->filterById($urlFilter->getViewId())
  ->findOne();
```

Note that here I also added a `filterByView('category')` call to the first method chain, to indicate I really only care about Category URLs.